# How to stop prettier from random line breaks?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

So Prettier is finicky as it is, but here's a weird situation. The image below shows what happens after a save in VS Code with Prettier set up normally. It randomly removed the tabs for these two lines. If I tab it back into place and save it does it again.
Can anyone tell me why, and how to stop it? Makes the code look really bad.

[image: weird line break]

Comment: if you need to indent that much you should redesign your code, you have 20 chars left on the line